# cakephp2: use paginate in model

Tags: cakephp

i wish use paginate in model, but when i insert paginate function, i get this error:

> Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You
>   have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to
>   your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'paginate'
>   at line 1

My code:

```
<?php
class Post extends AppModel
{
    public function get_posts()
    {
        $this->paginate = array(
            'fields' => array('Post.id', 'Post.title', 'Post.created'),
            'limit' => 3,
            'order' => array(
                'Post.created' => 'DESC'
            )           
        );

        $posts = $this->paginate('Post');

        return $posts;
    }
```

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`paginate()` is a controller method not a model method.